# How to import SQL Server Query in JSON format when data is large

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, ssms

I want to get 1000 rows from a table, but the result should be in in JSON format and then I need to export that file. But I am getting data in `clipped/truncated` format.

Command I used:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [ID]
      ,[Request]
      ,[Response]
  FROM [AuditLogs] for JSON AUTO
```

Options I tried:

1. I changed the default query result to exported to .rpt file. But when I open
   the rpt file in notepad++ the result are not completely exported.
2. I changed the default behavior to give result in .txt format, but again the result is truncated.

Question: All I want is the JSON result to be exported from SSMS. Please guide me.

P.S: The `response` column data might be long strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use below query - This will not truncate any data and the complete result will be stored in the @data variable.

```
  declare @data varchar(max) = (
  SELECT TOP (1000) [ID]
      ,[Request]
      ,[Response]
  FROM [AuditLogs] for JSON AUTO
  )   
print @data
```

Comment: Hi Mukesh, Can you see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951119/for-json-path-returns-less-number-of-rows-on-azure-sql

Comment: In the Answer's `COMMENT` Section, they are telling to use `@declare` but how do I get result set. Please guide me

Comment: use above mentioned query, It will print all the data in the SQL result window, you can copy and paste in the nodepad++ or any other editor. It will not truncate the data.

Comment: To get the resultset use `SELECT @data as AColumnName` instead of `print`

Comment: @MukeshArora you can do that until you get memory issues. In my case it prints to terminal just fine, copy and paste and it doesn't work.