# WPF C# JSON length issue

Tags: c#, sql, json, sql-server

Below is my code in C#. It is trying to get SQL result as JSON from database. I run this SQL query "SELECT XX FROM AA FOR JSON AUTO" in SQL server Management Studio, if the table has 5 rows, it is ok. But if the table has 2000 rows or more, then it will truncate the string result. Is there any method to allow C# to get full length of JSON result?

```
   SqlCommand query= new SqlCommand("SELECT XX FROM AA FOR JSON AUTO", cn);
                    cn.Open();
                    string JSON= query.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                    cn.Close();
```

Comment: Maybe you could use [openjson](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Maybe see [SQL Server json truncated (even when using NVARCHAR(max) )](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51087037/3744182) and/or [FOR JSON path returns less number of Rows on AZURE SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43951119/3744182).